# SQL Server : update table using records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, multiple-tables, sql-update

I have 2 tables `employee` and `employee_history` in a SQL Server 2012 database. The `employee` table contains the current information of all employees and the `employee_history` table keeps track of all changes that happened to the details of each employee.

My requirement is to update each record in the `employee` table with the most recent record for each employee from the `employee_history` table.

For example:

`employee` table:

[image]

`employee_history` table:

[image]

`employee` table after the update from `employee_history` table should be:

[image]

**Please note:** as this is only an example, I have added only minimum information. But, both the `employee` and `employee_history` tables have a lot of other columns. And there are some columns in each table that are not present in the other table. I am not supposed to update those columns.

Can you please tell me what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CTE to properly join tables.

```
;with hist as (
select *, row_number() over(partition by emp_id order by updated_date desc) rn
from employee_history
)
update employee
set Emp_First_Name = hist.Emp_First_Name --,more cols
from employee e
inner join hist on e.Emp_id = hist.emp_id and hist.rn = 1
```

Comment: No. left-side in update always belongs to the table to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
update a 
   set a.Emp_first_name = b.emp_first_name,
       a.emp_last_name  = b.emp_last_name, 
       a.Emp_Phone      = b.Emp_phone, 
       a.Emp_Address    = b.Emp_address, 
       a.Emp_dept       = b.Emp_dept
from employee as a
join  ( select * 
             , row_number over (partition by emp_id order by Updated_date  desc) as rn
        from employee_history  
      ) as b 
 on b.emp_id = a.emp 
and b.rn = 1
```

[update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)